# Specify guide legend aesthetics with multiple geom_point layers

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to create a scatter plot and highlight some points.

Using `mtcars` data:

```
library(ggplot2);library(dplyr)

ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=drat, y=mpg, fill =factor(gear)))+ 
        geom_point(pch =21)
```

This gives me the graph without any specific point highlighted, with the desired aesthetics for the legend guide.

[image]

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=drat, y=mpg, fill =factor(gear))) + 
         geom_point(pch =21) + 
         geom_point(data=filter(mtcars, hp >= 220), pch=22, color = 'red')
```

However, legend guide aesthetics were replaced by the aesthetics of the last layer of geom_point (squares highlighted in red)

[image]

How do I force the legend guide to be displayed with the aesthetics of the first geom_point layer (black circles)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `show.legned=FALSE` in your second layer:

```r
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=drat, y=mpg, fill =factor(gear))) + 
  geom_point(pch =21) + 
  geom_point(data=filter(mtcars, hp >= 220), pch=22, color = 'red', show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would like the color to be red, and keep the fill as mentioned in the aesthetics.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding for your question. You can set argument `show.legend = FALSE` in the second layer to make the layer not be included in the legend.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. A somewhat different approach using only one geom_point layer and setting shape and color using `scale_xxx_manual`, while using `guide_legend` to get the legend right.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(drat, mpg, fill = factor(gear), shape = hp >= 220, color = hp >= 220)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 22, "FALSE" = 21)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "red", "FALSE" = "black")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, fill = scales::hue_pal()(3), color = "black")),
         color = FALSE,
         shape = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>